# Java listen on entity's child collection change

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, events, collections

I'm trying to detect if entity's relation is updated, but nothing that I've tried or found is working.
What I have for short is like:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(KidsListener.class)
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Setter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private Long id;

    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Kid> kids = new HashSet<>(0);

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Long version;
}
```

I've tried both solutions - `EntityListeners` and implementing `PostCollectionUpdateEventListener`

```
public class KidsListener implements PostCollectionUpdateEventListener {
    @PostPersist
    @PostUpdate
    private void afterAnyUpdate(User user) {
        // do something
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostUpdateCollection(PostCollectionUpdateEvent event) {
        PersistentCollection collection = event.getCollection(); // do something
    }
}
```

Nothing of those works, even version for parent `User` entity isn't changing.

The save part is just something like:

```
User user = userRepository.findById(id);
for(Kid kid : mappedFromDto.getKids()){
    user.getKids().add(kid);
}
userRepository.save(user);
```

I can't listen on `Kid` change because I want to send out (in one request) a pack of all changes in User's kids.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I have to ask. Did you register the listener?

```
public class CustomIntegrator implements Integrator {

    public void integrate(
            Metadata metadata,
            SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
            SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        listenerRegistry.appendListeners(
            EventType.POST_COLLECTION_UPDATE,
            new KidsListener()
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void disintegrate(SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
    }
}
```

You also have to create a `META-INF/services/org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator` file that contains the fully qualified name of the integrator class.

After that, you should receive all events.

Please note that there are other events as well, like POST_COLLECTION_REMOVE and POST_COLLECTION_RECREATE that you might have to listen for as well to capture inserts/deletes.